# Final image render produces blurrier result than 3D Viewport's render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, reflection, shadowcatcher

I'm using Cycles and finding that the image I see in the 3D Viewport (when using rendered shading) is far crisper than the final render produced with *Render Image* (F12). I can't work out why.

First, the render as seen in the 3D Viewport (you can see the 3D Cursor) etc.:

[image: 3D viewport render]

And now the dramatically blurrier *Render Image* result:

[image: render image result]

I'm guessing this bluriness is somehow supposed to be truer? I.e. the crispness seen in the 3D Viewport is a result of not being such a *true* renderer, i.e. various short cuts (in addition to fewer passes) are at play here. Other differences, I can see are e.g. that the final render includes a definite shadow (that for some reason is not visible in the 3D Viewport view).

I've looked at the *Compositor* and *Shader* nodes and I see no obvious reason for the bluriness.

This sphere has been added into an environment created by tracking. I.e. I shot the background footage, solved for the camera motion and then let Blender set up the tracking scene which resulted in a cube (which I replace with a reflective sphere), a shadow-catchter plane and the following *Compositor* nodes:

[image: Compositor nodes]

And then I added my own HDRI (which you see reflected in the sphere) with the following *Shader* nodes:

[image: Shader nodes]

The `.hdr` file, the `.blend` file and the background `.mkv` can be found here:

- https://github.com/george-hawkins/blend-bin/tree/master/tracking-render
- https://github.com/george-hawkins/blend-bin/raw/master/tracking/clip-x264.mkv

Any insight into what's going on here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have motion blur enabled.  This, understandably, makes the render blurry.  Because motion blur can dramatically increase render times, it is not calculated for a rendered preview.

Comment: Super - I really appreciate people taking the time to answer questions that must seem painfully obvious to them but are completely non-obvious to people like me who are just trying things for the first time. I looked for issues with the nodes etc. and it never occurred to me that it might be a desirable effect, enabled to make things look better when movement is involved.

Comment: @GeorgeHawkins No problem-- I hope I didn't sound like I was talking down.  I know that it's often nice just to get another set of eyes on a problem.  In general, render/preview disagreement isn't going to be from mats, but from object visibility, render settings, subdivision settings, or particle settings.  There may be an exception here and there; it's kind of a shame that there's no "make it like preview" button.